# How to remove advertising software bundled with windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I bought a Windows 8 laptop from Fry's and saw that there were signs posted throughout the store warning people buying a Windows 8 laptop to ask an associate to help remove the advertising software in order to make the computer faster. The associate I asked said that it would cost 30$ to have them remove it, so I decided I would do it myself instead, figuring there has to be a tutorial on youtube for how to do that. To my surprise I haven't been able to find any tutorials on this subject. In fact I haven't found information on this subject at all. Even the Wikipedia page for Windows 8 doesn't seem to mention advertising software.

Comment: Yeah, I would take just about anything a Fry's employee tells you with a grain, no a whole teaspoon of salt...

Comment: What happens if you use the "Reset your PC" command in PC Settings? Does it remove the adware?

Comment: The signs were posted in many places throughout the store so it's either management or Frys corporation that recommends doing it. I'd be pretty surprised if it's an outright bold faced lie since that would hurt their reputation.

Comment: I've seen some ads in some of the "modern" apps, but those are easy to uninstall if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I suggest finding the advertising on your machine, and editing your question into _"How do I remove the add-on advertising that I've found at XYZ on my Windows 8 machine?"_ form.  Then _SuperUser_ will become the source of information on the subject for other people.

Comment: I've never tried it, but this might help: http://pcdecrapifier.com/

Comment: @gparyani I believe the Reset your PC returns it to the OEM state so any adware that was removed would be put back on.

Comment: $30?! One can buy a decent piece of hardware for that money!

Comment: @tumchaaditya You can't buy anything good for $30... Maybe a sound card or something.

Answer (score 2):

Windows itself does not come with advertising software, what it will have is the maker of the PC will include software to "subsidize" the cost of the PC to make it cheaper that is either time limited trial or contains advertisements built in.

Fry's is offering a service to uninstall the software HP, Lenovo, Dell, ect.. put on there to bring the cost of the computer down for you. There is no tutorial how to do it because all you are doing is just going in to Add/Remove programs and uninstalling any unnecessary or trial software you see.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Try [PCDecrapifier](http://pcdecrapifier.com/) which is a program that removes a lot of pre-installed programs. However, it's not perfect.
- Re-install windows (Tutorial [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc))